# Send android local HTML forms via ajax to remote php server

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there a way to send android local HTML forms via ajax to remote php server? (local means the files are in my device) My scenario is this: In my app, I have an html files in my android device and is loaded in a webview, i also have the javascript file in my device. What i want to do is to send the html forms data to a remote server. In my current situation, its not sending any data, I've check the javascript and php and the code is fine, and it's working on iOS version of the app. I've tried other workarounds and what I've observed is that, when i load html file in webview using local files (e.g. webview.loadUrl("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/android_asset/list.html"), the android is looking for all other related files (e.g. formsprocessor.php) locally, though in javascript/ajax all necessary arguments in it's functions are supplied properly. The errors i've encountered are: FileNotFound: content://packagename.com/formsprocessor.php & Unknown chronium error: -6.
Is there a way or what is the best way to do this?

Thanks, Clint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem:
Used a javascripthandler, and in my javascript i call the function from the handler. So basically, the android handled the upload of data to server using httppost. Here's the codes;

the handler:

```
final class IJavascriptHandler{
     IJavascriptHandler(){}

     public void sendJSONToAndroid(String text){
            if(!Config.canConnect((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE), home) && dialogNoConnFlag == false)                 {
                    dialogNoConnFlag = true;
                    Config.notificationMsg(Config.ERRORNOCONN,home, Config.TITLE1 + " " + Config.TITLE6);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    Log.v("SendToServer","Send JSON to Server");
                    String url = "";
                    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(text);
                    JSONArray names= json_data.names();
                    JSONArray values = json_data.toJSONArray(names);
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length(); i++){
                        Log.v("Good",names.getString(i).toString());
                        if(names.getString(i).equals("url")) {
                            url = json_data.getString(names.getString(i)).toString();
                        }
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair( names.getString(i).toString(),  json_data.getString(names.getString(i)).toString()));

                    }
                    Config.uploadToServer(nameValuePairs, url);
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                     Config.notificationMsg(Config.ERRORMSG + e.getMessage(), (Activity) home, Config.TITLE1 + " " + Config.TITLE6);
                }
           }

    }
```

the httppost:

```
    public static String uploadToServer(List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs, String url){
    if(Session.isordinaryHost)
    {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
    else
    {
        httpclient = new MyHttpClient().getNewHttpClient();
        ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
              new AuthScope(Session.siteIp, 443), 
              new UsernamePasswordCredentials(Session.siteUsername, Session.sitePassword));
    }
    httppost = new HttpPost(url);  
    try 
    {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
        EntityUtils.toString(entity);  
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
         return e.getMessage();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
         return e.getMessage();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

the javascript:

```
function CheckCompleteRecords() {
DB.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(SelectCompleteForUploadStatement, [], function(tx, result) { 
    Dataset = result.rows;
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < Dataset.length; i++) {
            item = Dataset.item(i);
    var a = createJSON(item['FormName'],item['UserID'],item['Image1'],item['Image2'],item['Image3'],item['Image4'],item['Image5'],item['Field1'],item['Field2'],item['Field3'],item['Field4'],item['Field5'],item['Field6'],item['Field7'],item['Field8'],item['Field9'],item['Field10'],item['Field11'],item['Field12'],item['Field13'],item['Field14'],item['Field15'],item['Field16'],item['Field17'],item['Field18'],item['Field19'],item['Field20'],item['Field21'],item['Field22'],item['Field23'],item['Field24'],item['Field25'],item['Field26'],item['Field27'],item['Field28'],item['Field29'],item['Field30'],item['Field31'],item['Field32'],item['Field33'],item['Field34'],item['Field35'],item['Field36'],item['Field37'],item['Field38'],item['Field39'],item['Field40'],item['Field41'],item['Field42'],item['Field43'],item['Field44'],item['Field45'],item['Field46'],item['Field47'],item['Field48'],item['Field49'],item['Field50'],item['Field51'],item['Field52'],item['Field53'],item['Field54'],item['Field55'],item['Field56'],item['Field57'],item['Field58'],item['Field59'],item['Field60'],item['Field61'],item['Field62'],item['Field63'],item['Field64'],item['Field65'],item['Field66'],item['Field67'],item['Field68'],item['Field69'],item['Field70'],item['Field71'],item['Field72'],item['Field73'],item['Field74'],item['Field75'],item['Field76'],item['Field77'],item['Field78'],item['Field79'],item['Field80'],item['Field81'],item['Field82'],item['Field83'],item['Field84'],item['Field85'],item['Field86'],item['Field87'],item['Field88'],item['Field89'],item['Field90'],item['Field91'],item['Field92'],item['Field93'],item['Field94'],item['Field95'],item['Field96'],item['Field97'],item['Field98'],item['Field99'],item['Field100'],item['CurrentDateTime'],item['Geolocation'],item['BarCode']);                             
    window.cpjs.sendJSONToAndroid(a);

            showStuff('SendServerBtn');
            window.location = "senttoserver://app_action";
    }
    });
});
}
```